# How to add sub menu in quick links?

Tags: php, yii

Hi i want to add sub menu under main menu in quick links please help me

this is added in view

```
$this->menu=array(
        array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/school/view')),
        array('label'=>'Create a Student', 'url'=>array('student/create')),
        array('label'=>'Import Students', 'url'=>array('student/ImportStudents')),
        array('label'=>'Attendance', 'url'=>array('attendance/admin')),
        array('label'=>'Create Subjects', 'url'=>array('schoolsubjectdetails/create')),
        array('label'=>'Upload Marks', 'url'=>array('markdetails/create')),
        array('label'=>'Download Mark List', 'url'=>array('markdetails/admin')),
        array('label'=>'School Performance', 'url'=>array('markdetails/schoolperformance')),
        array('label'=>'Subject Performance', 'url'=>array('markdetails/subjectperformance')),
    );
```

this is my column layout

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" >
                <div class="sidebar1">
                    <div data-scrollable="" tabindex="0" style="overflow-y: hidden; outline: none;">
                        <h4 class="category">Quick Links</h4>
                        <ul class="sidebar-block list-group list-group-menu list-group-minimal">
                            <?php 
                            if(isset($this->menu))
                            {/* 
                                echo '<pre>';
                                print_r($this->menu);
                                exit; */
                                foreach($this->menu as $mnu):

                            ?>
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <a style="display:block;text-decoration:none" href="<?php echo $this->createUrl($mnu['url'][0]) ?>"><?php echo $mnu['label'] ?></a>
                                </li>
                            <?php 
                                endforeach;
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my url manager

```
<?php

class UrlManager extends CUrlManager
{
    public function createUrl($route,$params=array(),$ampersand='&')
    {
        if (!isset($params['language'])) 
        {
            if (Yii::app()->user->hasState('language'))
                Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->user->getState('language');
            else if(isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['language']))
                Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->request->cookies['language']->value;
            $params['language']=Yii::app()->language;
        }
        return parent::createUrl($route, $params, $ampersand);
    }
}

?>
```

in this above program i have 9 menu in my quick link home,Create a student, import students, attendance, create subjects, upload marks, download marks, school performance, subject performance i don't want to be like this how it should display means home, student if we click student is show sub menu as create a student and import student, attendance, Mark if we click mark it should display create subjects, upload marks, download marks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a menu widget like this ([from Yii doc CMenu Class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu) )

> ```
>     $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
>         'items'=>array(
>             // Important: you need to specify url as 'controller/action',
>             // not just as 'controller' even if default action is used.
>             array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('site/index')),
>             // 'Products' menu item will be selected no matter which tag parameter value is since it's not specified.
>             array('label'=>'Products', 'url'=>array('product/index'), 'items'=>array(
>                 array('label'=>'New Arrivals', 'url'=>array('product/new', 'tag'=>'new')),
>                 array('label'=>'Most Popular', 'url'=>array('product/index', 'tag'=>'popular')),
>             )),
>             array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
>         ),
>     ));
> ```

Comment: its working but not as i expected.it simple shows how the index page in book i don't want like that on click it should drop-down the sub menu again if i click it should hide the sub menu like toggle.